# Automatically add namespace based on path to embedded VB.NET resources

Tags: vb.net, build, embedded-resource

I am used to embedding resources in C# and I like the way it automatically adds namespaces to the embedded resources. That allows me to do things like this:

```
files\version1\config.xml
files\version2\config.xml
files\version2\config.xml
```

Unfortunately, if you try the same in a VB.NET project you'll get compile errors, since it tries to put all embedded resources into the root namespace. To get around this I can manually edit the `.vbproj` file like so:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="files\version1\config.xml">
  <LogicalName>$(RootNamespace).files.version1.config.xml</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="files\version2\config.xml">
  <LogicalName>$(RootNamespace).files.version2.config.xml</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="files\version3\config.xml">
  <LogicalName>$(RootNamespace).files.version3.config.xml</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

While this works, it's manual, time consuming and error prone so my question is this:
Can a build task or build event be written do this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

This is a side effect of how Visual Basic does not use folder paths to create namespaces by default.

Personally, other then the specific case, your talking about I prefer it not having all the additional folder paths in the name. I hope MS adds another property to the file resources to allow a namespace to be set specifically in the future, but until then....

The solution is quite simple though.

**Create a resource-only dll in C# and read your resources from there**. As a VB developer I would not think twice about doing this to satisfy that specific purpose.

**EDIT**.
OR... can use a vbs file as a prebuild event to copy files to a new resource directory in the format needed to make the simulated namespace.

```
dim fSys
set fsys=createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim root : root= "c:\temp"
dim out : out="c:\temp\DynResource"

dim rFo: set rFo=fsys.getfolder(root)
dim outPath

for each sf in rFo.SubFolders
    if instr(1, sf.name, "Version")>=1 then 'valid resource folder
        for each f in sf.Files
            outpath = out & "\" & sf.name & "." & f.name
            if fsys.FileExists(output) then
                dim tf:set tf=fsys.getfile(output)
                if tf.length<>f.length or tf.DateLastModified<>f.DateLastModified then
                    f.copy outPath,true
                else
                    'same file, no update required.
                end if 
            else
                f.copy outPath,true
            end if
        next
    end if 
next
```

Output foldere must already exist (and obviously cannot have "Version" in the folder name).

Comment: I suppose simple depends on how you look at it. Adding a whole other project just to achieve this is easy yes, but I wouldn't call it simple.  Not to mention the fact that I'd either have to distribute another dll or combine them post build.  I'll up-vote this as an alternative, but I can't accept it as the answer as I am looking for a build task or build event that can accomplish this within the same project.

Comment: True enouhg, I don't like adding too many DLL's either. What about about keeping all your files in the format similar to what you have. but then just write a short VBS script that can loop through the "Version..." folders and append them together into one output directory. Just add a check to see that the file has changed first so it doesn't re-write each file each time. Once you have marked all those files as embedded resources overwritting them will not reset that. Again it is more of a bandaid then a proper way to do it, but you could at least remove the manual part.