# Embeded Image Resources Extended Namespace in VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm used to C#, but I'm currently working on a standard VB.Net Winforms project.

In this project I added an "images" folder where each image has Build Action set to Embedded Resource.

```
--ProjectName
  --images
    --filename1.bmp
    --filename2.bmp
    --filename3.bmp
```

I can get these images using the following static Method.

```
Public Shared Function GetImageResource(fileName As String) As Image
  Dim resourceName as string = string.Format("ProjectName.{0}",fileName)

  Dim thisExe = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  Dim file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)

  if (file is nothing ) Then Return Nothing

  return Image.FromStream(file)

End Function
```

In C# the resource name will use the folder names in the namespace like this: "ProjectName.**FolderName**.FileName.ext"

However, VB.Net doesn't use the folder names in the namespace and resources are simply: 
"ProjectName.FileName.ext"

**Can I somehow manually add the folder namespace in VB.Net**?
We will be embedding several groups of images (in folders), and would like to organize them by namespaces rather than dumping them all into the same namespace together.

Comment: This may not be your solution, but I would create a separate project for your resources (it can even be in C#) and link to it in the VB project. This keeps your main executable from bloating and makes it easy to update/change image resources without having to send out a new program.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860969/automatically-add-namespace-based-on-path-to-embedded-vb-net-resources